# What is the difference between the code below?

Tags: python, pandas

What is the difference between these two lines of code?

```py
print(df.drop(df.where(df['Quantity']==0).index).rename(columns={'Weight':'Weight(oz)'}))
```

and

```py
print(df.drop(df[df['Quantity'] == 0].index).rename(columns={'Weight': 'Weight (oz.)'}))
```

In other words, what is the difference between

```py
df.where(df['Quantity']==0).index
```

with the following output

[image]

And

```py
df[df['Quantity'] == 0].index
```

with the following output

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difference because it uses [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
df.where(df['Quantity']==0).index
```

it only replace non matched rows to `NaN`s, so the index of the result is the same as the original `df`.

---

But if you use:

```
df[df['Quantity'] == 0].index
```

it is called [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and it filters the `DataFrame` by condition, so index values are different from the original `df`.

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Quantity':[0,1,2,1,1,0],
                   'Weight':  [4,5,6,7,7,8]},
                    index=list('abcdef'))
print (df)
   Quantity  Weight
a         0       4
b         1       5
c         2       6
d         1       7
e         1       7
f         0       8

#removed all index values - empty DataFrame
print(df.drop(df.where(df['Quantity']==0).index).rename(columns={'Weight':'Weight(oz)'}))  
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Quantity, Weight(oz)]
Index: []

print (df.where(df['Quantity']==0).index)
Index(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], dtype='object')

print (df.where(df['Quantity']==0))
   Quantity  Weight
a       0.0     4.0
b       NaN     NaN
c       NaN     NaN
d       NaN     NaN
e       NaN     NaN
f       0.0     8.0
```

---

```
#removed rows with 0 in Quantity
print(df.drop(df[df['Quantity'] == 0].index).rename(columns={'Weight': 'Weight (oz.)'}))
   Quantity  Weight (oz.)
b         1             5
c         2             6
d         1             7
e         1             7

print (df[df['Quantity'] == 0].index)
Index(['a', 'f'], dtype='object')

print (df[df['Quantity'] == 0])
   Quantity  Weight
a         0       4
f         0       8
```

In my opinion solution with `drop` is overcomplicated, simplier is use inverse logic - select all rows with no `0` in `Quantity` column:

```
print(df[df['Quantity'] != 0].rename(columns={'Weight': 'Weight (oz.)'}))
   Quantity  Weight (oz.)
b         1             5
c         2             6
d         1             7
e         1             7
```

Comment: Thanks @jezreal. So df.drop on df.where is dropping the entire dataframe ? because it is enitre dataframe ?

Comment: @Sushant - because `where` only replace values to NaNs, not filtering